# Remap Caps Lock key to 'Run Command' (Alt+F2)

Tags: shortcut-keys, xmodmap, capslock

I'm trying to get rid of the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>key and give it a better use. Since I constantly use the `run` command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, I'd like to make Caps Lock trigger that action.

I've found a couple of questions related, using `xmodmap`, but none of them try to map Caps Lock to a combination of keys such as Alt+F2

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: After certain versions, you can't use super or cap alone for shortcuts.  At least can't configure it that way in the keyboard shortcut gui.

Comment: Please have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041674/can-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key-to-play-audio/1047003#1047003 You should be able to adapt this answer for your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install [Xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)
   [image: Install xdotool]  and [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)
   [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] from *Ubuntu Software Center*
2. Disable Caps-Lock by opening **Keyboard Preferences**

   `System ▸ Preferences ▸ Keyboard`

   Goto tab `Layouts` then click the button `Options...`

   Change the key behaviour to *CapsLock is disabled*

   [image]
3. Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager*

   - Use *Run Command*, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and type `ccsm`
4. Enable ***Commands*** plugin then add the following

   - Add `xdotool key alt+F2` to the first available command slot
   - Goto 'Key Bindings' tab. In the same slot number assign Caps Lock key.

     *Note: It will show VoidSymbol as the button assigned but this is fine.*

     [image]

     [image]

Comment: When I try to add caps lock to the key bindings, it displays `0xffffff`, but no key binding is stored when I close the window

Answer (score 1):

Going by what you mention [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35783/map-capslock-key-to-alt-f2-ie-run-command/35818#35818). You can *disable* CAPS LOCK by going to `System ▸ Preferences ▸ Keyboard`. Then in the window that opens `Layouts ▸ Options...`. Here you can change the CapsLock key behaviour and disable it.

Comment: Ok, and what about having 'capslock' as a substitute of 'alt+f2' for 'run command'? The only issue would be assigning an empty action to that key but still have it enabled, so I can use the 'keyboard settings' module to assign the 'run command' action to 'capslock' and NOT have it actually turn the capslock ON every time I hit it. Can you see what I mean?